# Strategy to convert visual force to lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Sorry to be too broad. I have a client now who is in the process of converting their org to Lightning. There are a lot of `Visualforce Pages` in use. We are in the process of evaluating whether or not we need to convert everything to lightning or inject lightning inside `Visualforce`. Here are some specific use cases which I would like to have an opinion on:

1. I have `Visualforce Pages` embedded on standard or custom object detail pages like `Accounts`, `Opportunities`, etc. If we migrate to lightning, does it make sense to convert these `Visualforce Pages` to the lightning framework?
2. If there are independent `Visualforce Pages` which are multi-step wizards, does converting these to lightning provide any advantage? If so how do you transfer data from one `Visualforce Page` to another?

Has anyone here converted either of the above 2 use cases to lightning?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why people are marking this as "too broad". Ok it is broad, but seems like a good question relevant to many of us (and of more lasting value than how to fix a random piece of code). Here is some opinion and I would certainly appreciate reading answers from others.

The last time I looked the core step is to make sure the Visualforce pages work in Lightning Experience as well as Classic. (Trailhead has [various articles](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/lex_admin_migration) on that.) You then have something to review and consider.

Then a second step is to consider tweaking the styling manually to better match the [Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning/design-system). (Though waiting until Visualforce has that support built in seems more rational - but see the PS.)

If those pages work and are reasonably useable and not too ugly (and cleanly coded so they are easy to change as needed) then a re-implementation might not make sense at all. But you may decide that you do want to re-implement some or all of them. Embedding Lightning in multiple pages has the big disadvantage that the framework startup adds delay to the opening of each page. So re-implementing an area of the application where you can stay in one Lightning app (page?) is likely to produce a more responsive result.

**PS**

On the point about support in Visualforce for SLDS styling, there is presently no prospect of that ever happening.